# How to Implement Multiplication Algorithm using Visual C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am new to C++ programming, I would like to write a visual C++ program to implement the below Algorithm. My issue is that I don't know how to declare variables in Binary, and how to set the size of binary numbers too. Can any one help me in the functions needed for:

1. Increase size for binary number say from 5 bits to 64 and 32 bits
2. The functions needed for addition, shifting

below is the algorithm which should be easy to code if I know the above.

p.s. if there is a function that convert from decimal to binary that would be great. this is for a college project.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To put your questions in a better way, please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Do a basic ground research and ask questions about a specific problem that you are facing.

Comment: Learn the basics of programming and C++ before trying to do this.